# Flutter - Transform scale in center of Container

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a flip effect, but before starting with the animation I'm trying to make the transformation stay in the center of the container.

But even using `FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.5)` or `Center()` wrapping the `Transform()` result remains on the top of the `Container`, as in the image below.

Could you help me leave it in the center of the container?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              alignment: new FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.5),
              height: 144.0,
              width: 360.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border: new Border.all(color: new Color(0xFF9E9E9E))
              ),
              child: new Transform(
                transform: new Matrix4.identity()..scale(1.0, 0.05),   
                  child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: new Color(0xFF005CA9),        
                  ),        
                ), 
              )         
            )         
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Transform](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Transform-class.html) doesn't affect the layout of its child, it only affects how the child is painted.

If you want to do the scaling with your `Transform`, you can pass an `alignment: FractionalOffset.center`.

If you want to center the item with layout primitives instead, you can use [`FractionallySizedBox`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FractionallySizedBox-class.html) instead of `Transform`.

For a full example of how to animate a flip effect, see my answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990714/flutter-effect-of-flip-card).

[image: screenshot]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              alignment: new FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.5),
              height: 144.0,
              width: 360.0,
              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                border: new Border.all(color: new Color(0xFF9E9E9E))
              ),
              child: new Transform(
                alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                transform: new Matrix4.identity()..scale(1.0, 0.05),
                child: new Container(
                  decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                    color: new Color(0xFF005CA9),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What I'm trying to do is a flip card. You would have a suggestion of which way to go to have the following effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rViwsJvxz7M

Comment: Please revise your question to ask that question instead (or start a new question), and I'd be happy to answer it.

Comment: Thanks, I opened the following question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44990714/flutter-effect-of-flip-card

Comment: Thanks! I'll answer it now.

Answer (score 4):

Just add this into your container:

```dart
alignment: FractionalOffset.center
```